# how to display htmlwidgets inside openCPU apps?

Tags: r, opencpu

We want to display an htmlwidget inside an OpenCPU application.The html is generated by Leaflet without problems, however we have some troubles to display it within the OpenCPU app. We used the following function to generate the Leaflet Map:

```
leafmap1 <- function(ecoregion='10105',wdpa_id='1500'){
require(leaflet)
require(shiny)
require(htmlwidgets)
m <- leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m 
}
```

The JavaScript is as follows:

```
function SochiCtrl($scope){
$scope.ecoregions = ['10105']
$scope.wdpa_ids = ["1500"]
$scope.ecoregion = $scope.ecoregions[0]
$scope.wdpa_id = $scope.wdpa_ids[0]    
$scope.makeChart = function(){
   var req = ocpu.rpc("leafmap1", 
    {"ecoregion": $scope.ecoregion, "wdpa_id": $scope.wdpa_id}, function(output){   
    $('#map').html(output)
   }).fail(function(text){
     alert("Error: " + req.responseText);
   });
}
$scope.$watchCollection('[ecoregion, wdpa_id]', function(newValues){
  console.log(newValues)
  $scope.makeChart({ecoregion: newValues[0], wdpa_id: newValues[1]})
})
}
```

Now the app shows the Leaflet frame but I have some problems getting the json from OpenCPU I got the following error *No method asJSON S3 class: htmlwidget*. I also tried with:

```
m <- toJSON(m, force= TRUE)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
[image]

The full code is available at: https://github.com/Arevaju/ocpuleaflet.

Thanks a lot for your help and congratulations for your great work!!

Comment: Can you include some example code of a widget you'd like to display?

Comment: No solution found?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this repo from Jeroen: https://github.com/opencpu/leafletapp. You will find the app at the OpenCPU website. Our working example can be found at: https://github.com/javimarlop/spdynmodocpu

Answer (score 2):

Sorry as this is not a tested answer, but this is easier to explain a proposed approach here than in a comment.

What I propose is to have your function `leafmap1` return plain text (HTML) instead of the leaflet object.

You can see that the leaflet object inherits the class `htmlwidget`.
For this class, there exists a method for the generic function `toHTML` that would allows retrieving such HTML code.

Assumed a leaflet object:

```
 m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
```

Let's have a look at it's class:

```
class(m)
[1] "leaflet"    "htmlwidget"
```

Get the underlying generated html:

```
> (out <- unclass(htmlwidgets:::toHTML(m)))
[[1]]
<div id="htmlwidget-7863" style="width:100%;height:400px;" class="leaflet html-widget"></div>
[[2]]
<script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-7863">{"x":{"calls":[{"method":"addTiles","args":    ["http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",null,null,{"minZoom":0,"maxZoom":18,"maxNativeZoom":null,"tileSize":256,"subdomains":"abc","errorTileUrl":"","tms":false,"continuousWorld":false,"noWrap":false,"zoomOffset":0,"zoomReverse":false,"opacity":1,"zIndex":null,"unloadInvisibleTiles":null,"updateWhenIdle":null,"detectRetina":false,"reuseTiles":false,"attribution":"&copy; <a href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\">OpenStreetMap\u003c/a> contributors, <a href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA\u003c/a>"}]}]},"evals":[],"jsHooks":[]}</script>
[[3]]
NULL
attr(,"html_dependencies")
attr(,"html_dependencies")[[1]]
[...]
```

Third slot contains dependancies (javascript+css) so I guess those are already loaded in your report.

You may return the concatenation of the first two components (function result):

```
return(paste(out[[1]], out[[2]], sep="\n"))
```

Comment: Nice, but how do you include the html in your script? Do you mind precise the js call on the client side?

Comment: I worked only once with opencpu, years ago. Does adding in HTML a div element and append the result to it? Sich as `$('#results').append("<br/>");`(found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418535/how-to-call-an-self-designed-r-function-on-opencpu-via-javascript)

Comment: tryed session.getObject(function(outtxt){
   $("#my_div").text(outtxt);
  });
and   <div id="my_div"></div> and didn't worked. Maybe in a way I am not aware.

Comment: Can you try with append?

Comment: Append add the underlying generated html. I have tried it but still miss something. The html copied/paste(plus a call of the css and js scripts) does not produce the graph so far. The bounty period come to an end so I'll give you the reward for the answer (the concept to return part of the code and manually set up the css and js library is a good one)

Comment: I can't find the toHTML function anywhere in the docs (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlwidgets/htmlwidgets.pdf). Am I missing something ?

Comment: Sorry for delays -- didn't connect to stackOverflow before. You may see in my code that function is indeed not exported (visible) thus the ":::" before calling.